# prevent users from killing each others job in queue

Tags: apache-spark

what are the setting needed or any other framework required to prevent users from killing each others spark job submitted to master and visible on localhost:8080. I want a situation where only admin or the user who submitted the job will be able to kill that job and no other user.

Comment: Do you mean killing with `kill -9 pid`?

Comment: its through web GUI whch has kill options, not kill -9